# Как получить в какой элемент вложен другой элемент?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть элемент

```
<div class="element1">
    <div class="element2">
        Текст
    </div>
</div>
```

И код который получает element2

```
let element = document.getElementByClassName("element2")
```

Как получить element1 имея element2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как получить element1 имея element2?

Например так

```js
const e2 = document.querySelector('.element2')
let e1 = e2.parentNode
console.log(e1)

// или так
e1 = e2.closest('.element1')
console.log(e1)
```

```html
<div class="element1">
    <div class="element2">
        Текст
    </div>
</div>
```